# Making relationships between nodes using graphdb

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, jersey

I am very new to graph-db and now I'm trying to do basics of that using examples. below is the sample code which i tried and I am trying to make relationship between three nodes. I am trying to get the below as o/p.

**my code**

```
        private static final String DB_PATH = "/home/nnn/Documents/softwares/neo4j-community-2.0.1";

public String greeting;


GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
Node firstNode;
Node secondNode;
Node thirdNode;

Relationship relationship;

private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
{
    LIKES
}

public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    G1 hello = new G1();
    hello.createDb();
    hello.removeData();
    hello.shutDown();
}

void createDb()
{
    clearDb();

    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
    registerShutdownHook( graphDb );

    try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
    {

        firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
        firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Alice " );
        secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
        secondNode.setProperty( "message", "Bob" );
        thirdNode = graphDb.createNode();
        thirdNode.setProperty( "message", "Anu" );

        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.LIKES);
        relationship.setProperty( "message", "likes " );

        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( thirdNode, RelTypes.LIKES);
        relationship.setProperty( "message", "likes " );

        System.out.print( firstNode.getProperty("message"));
        System.out.print( relationship.getProperty( "message" ) );
        System.out.print( secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) );


        System.out.print( firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
       //System.out.print( relationship.getProperty( "message" ) );
        //System.out.print( thirdNode.getProperty( "message" ) );


        greeting = ( (String) firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) )
                   + ( (String) relationship.getProperty( "message" ) )
                   + ( (String) secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) )
                   + ( (String) thirdNode.getProperty( "message" ) );

        tx.success();
    }

}

private void clearDb()
{
    try
    {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively( new File( DB_PATH ) );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
}

void removeData()
{
    try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
    {

        firstNode.getSingleRelationship( RelTypes.LIKES, Direction.OUTGOING ).delete();
        firstNode.delete();
        secondNode.delete();
        thirdNode.delete();

        tx.success();
    }
}

void shutDown()
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "Shutting down database ..." );

    graphDb.shutdown();

}


private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
{

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    } );
}

}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire method?

Comment: also your "message" properties make no sense, they should be `name` properties. For the relationship you need **no** property that repeats the rel-type.

Comment: You didn't show where the Exception happens. I think you shouldn't get started with the Java API, take the online course (http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course), learn cypher and start from there.

Comment: @Luanne i edited my post and added my entire code

Answer (score 1):

As the exception indicates, you're calling

```
firstNode.getSingleRelationship( RelTypes.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING ).delete();
```

when you have more than one outgoing relation of type KNOWS from firstNode
(firstNode->secondNode and firstNode->thirdNode)

Maybe you want to use http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.1/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getRelationships(org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction) instead

As for the output, you want to get all the relations from the first node to be able to get the end node of each relation.

Answer (score 0):

You created two outgoing `KNOWS` relationships for your `firstNode`.

If you want to delete them all do:

```
for (Relationship rel : node.getRelationships()) {
   rel.delete();
}
```

You can pass direction and type parameters to that method too.

**But if you want to delete a node, all its relationships have to be deleted first.**